# MySQL \ join 2 tables product and image table

Tags: mysql

1.When we add record product details product table with image and without image.

2.what is the query - product details added without image.

what is the query for fetching both table data when image not available of any one product.

```
Product table 
-----------------------------
ID | product_name | Size
-----------------------------
1  | TShirt 1      | S
2  | TShirt 2      | S
3  | TShirt 3      | S
4  | TShirt 4      | S
-----------------------------
```

Image table

---

### ID | image_name | ref_id

### 1  | tshirt1.jpg |  1

### 2  | tshirt2.jpg |  2

### 3  | tshirt3.jpg |  3

Comment: please edit with dots, commas. Question is hard to understand

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Come on, this is basic knowledge easily found in any reference or tutorial on SQL.

Comment: Yes i write query for that condition but i m facing problem when i execute query then only those records show which is having image.rest are not showing

Comment: @rakeshshriwas I don't believe you

Answer (score 0):

1.SELECT Product_name,Size FROM Product_table, Image_Table ON
Product_table.ID=Image_table.ref_id WHERE image_name = IS NOT NULL;

2.SELECT Product_name,Size FROM Product_table, Image_Table ON
Product_table.ID=Image_table.ref_id WHERE image_name IS NULL;

Answer (score 0):

Select all Products where the Image is missing (NULL).

`SELECT * 
FROM Product 
INNER JOIN Image ON Product.ID = Image.ID 
WHERE image_name IS NULL;`